# Updating data for UITableView in background breaks animations

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController which is supposed to fetch data in the background and then refresh the UITableView. However when I run the update method in the background it breaks all transition animations in the entire app (Slides when pushing view controllers on to the navigation stack). Weirdly, the exact same model works in other classes very similar to this one.
Here is the call I'm using for background updating:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateData) withObject:nil];
```

However this works, but is of course not done in the background:

```
[self updateData];
```

And finally the method being run:

```
- (void)updateData{
    updating = YES;
    [progress show:YES];
    dataSource = [[NetworkHandler sharedInstance:self] getRaces];
    [progress hide:YES];
    updating = NO;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The updating flag is not in any way an attempt at a semaphore, merely a way to ensure that the view doesn't get updated twice in case the user switches back and forth between views. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[self.tableView reloadData];` looks like it could cause some kind of threading issue. All updates to the UI should be done in the main thread. So this should work:

`[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)];`

Comment: I'll try, it does however work in other classes. I did find one difference and that is that I have my own reference to the UITableView there, hooked up in IB. Whereas in this class I'm just using the one found in UITableViewController.

Comment: You should make sure that everything you do that ends up updating the UI should be executed on the main thread

Comment: I'm going to take my previous statement back, the exact same code works in another class. The problem with calling that method on the main thread is that it locks up the app, I'd like a solution where the items are added in the background.

Comment: Added to what, data source or table view? They are being added to the data source in the background. If your UI is still sluggish there might be something else causing it.

Comment: Quite true, turns out I was fetching images from a server in a method called when reloading the table. Fixed that and now it works like a charm. Weirdly enough this also fixed the original issue, so the code works when calling reloadData in the background thread.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that while updating the UI in a background thread _may_ work _sometimes_, it will eventually fail in sometimes subtle, sometimes not-so-subtle ways. For example, I recently had a tableView class that would automatically switch out the data source depending on the state of the data -- waiting for data, no data, or some data. Somewhere a dev called the switch method on a background thread. After that the first row of the tableView would show _two different cells_ for 20 seconds or so -- the "waiting" cell and the "data" cell. TL;DR:don't do it.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons What do you suggest then? My tableview is crashing when I press reload button while it's being scrolled. Disabling scrolling while updates and updating while scrolling doesn't seem quite right to me.

Answer (score 1):

As of February 2015, the method mentioned in the answer above is deprecated, and replaced by:

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```